# How to get folder path of file opened from OpenFileDialog in Visual Basic 2013

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I am opening a file using `OpenFileDialog`. My code is as follows -

```
Public Sub ShowOpenDialog()
Dim f As New OpenFileDialog
f.InitialDirectory = GetFolderPath(SpecialFolder.MyDocuments)
f.Title = "Open File"
f.CheckFileExists = True
f.CheckPathExists = True
f.DefaultExt = "*.txt"
f.Filter = "Text (*.txt)|*.txt|All Files|*.*"
f.FilterIndex = 1
f.RestoreDirectory = True
If f.ShowDialog() = DialogResult.OK Then
'f.FileName displays file path, what I need is its folder path
'Performing action with f.FileName
End If
End Sub
```

**I also need file's location (folder path), but I couldn't find, how to get it?**

p.s. - I (also) need to open the file, so I have to use `OpenFileDialog` instead of `FolderBrowserDialog`. That's why, I am searching for a way to get file's Folder Path from `OpenFileDialog`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This returns the parent folder name. (Works for Files and Folders (Folders, which do not end with "\"))

```
    ''Be sure to   Import Imports System.IO
Function GetDirPath(ByVal file As String) As String
    Dim fi As New FileInfo(file)
    Return fi.Directory.ToString
End Function
```